# Accessing the name of the page in ERB

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am building a website with Sinatra and ERB templates. Within the ERB I would like to access the name of the page being loaded and change a small part of the layout accordingly.

For example, my routes are like:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

I need something like:

```
<% unless page_is_index %>
    <!-- HTML goes here -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Set name of the page on the controller side, and than use it in erb.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct relation in Sinatra between routing and controllers, so there isn't `current_controller` and `current_action` helpers like in Rails. What you can do is checking `request.path`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different layout which makes the changes you need. If nothing else, this layout could just include the main layout with more options.

```
get '/' do
  erb :index, :layout => 'index_layout'
end
```